# mod_rewrite 301 Redirect: from old to new dynamic url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get a mod_rewrite working correctly.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page=product_info&products_id=301$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$          
/blog/shop/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=301? [R=301,L]
```

It works, but in the end of the new URL %3f is added. 
Can somebody help me to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Put no-escape flag NE at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$          
/blog/shop/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=301? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

%3f is the question mark at the end of your statement. Take that out and you should be good.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page=product_info&products_id=301$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$          
/blog/shop/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=301 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks, but the url has still %3f in the end:
blog/shop/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=301%3f

Comment: Is your browser caching the response? That's odd that there's *no* change. Either Petr or my responses should have been your solution...

Answer (score 0):

%3f is the "?" you have at the end of your "Target URL" - just URL escaped. Is this really supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0):

The `%3f` is the `?` at the end of your replacement in percent-encoding. Just drop the `?` at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page=product_info&products_id=301$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /blog/shop/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=301 [R=301,L]
```

You would only use a `?` at the end to indicate an empty query so that the requested query does not get appended to the new URL if it does not contain a query.

Comment: thanks, I took the ? away - but the url has still %3f in the end:
blog/shop/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=301%3f

Comment: Probably the old redirection is cached in your browser.